# How can change element in NUXT.js with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Now, I've been using NUXT with my own Django for a bit. I would like to know how in VUE I can add a button to the next video.

```
  <video id="movieads" class="center" width="640" controls>
  <source src="https://cdn.videvo.net/videvo_files/video/free/2013-08/small_watermarked/hd0983_preview.webm" type="video/webm">

</video>
<button v-on:click="">Next VDO</button>
```

And in javascripts i will use `document.getElementById('movieads').src = OTHER_URL;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
methods: {
    Change() {
      console.log("Skip Ads");
      this.$refs.youtube.src =
        "OTHERVDO";
      console.log(this.$refs.youtube.src);
    }
  },
```